# Android Studio not detecting device but DDMS and IntelliJ are

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9. The issue, it is not detecting my device. I tried it with a couple of different devices. "adb devices" on the command line shows the device. adb logcat on the command line works. DDMS view (Android Device Monitor) recognizes the device and shows logcat too! But the Android Studio shell does not show it. I'm at my wit's end. I have tried restarting everything involved in the process - Android Studio, adb, my phone and even my Mac. Nothing helped. It's not a one-off problem either - I have had this 2 weeks ago, tried everything I could. Gave up and worked on something else. Now I'm back to working on Android and the issue is still there. I suspect it's something to do with my Studio config, but haven't been able to figure it out.
update: I downloaded IntelliJ and that is working fine too. So either I'm running into a weird bug in Android Studio that nobody else seems to be facing, or my Android Studio settings are wrong!

Comment: go to Run -> Edit configurations. Select the project and find the area for target device.

Comment: did you turn on debugging mode from developer options?>

Comment: I do have debugging mode turned on, that's why the device is visible through command line adb and through DDMS.

Answer (score 1):

***Follow the steps !***

---

- **Step1>** Connect your phone to computer via USB Enable USB `debugging` on your phone
- **Step2>** Right click on `project` -> `Run As` -> `Run Configuration`
- **Step3>** There are three tabs, Here select the second tab
- **Step4>** In your project and check if your mobile device is detected ? If yes the click on it and Click `Run button.`